# Does a custom VPN really ensure privacy?

Tags: security, proxy, vpn, privacy

My question concerns custom VPNs (with one single user). One configures a VPS on a cloud service provider and then uses it as a proxy/ VPN, so that all traffic going from or to the user's computer needs to pass, encrypted, through the VPS. Let's call the personal computer A and the VPS V. Now I will argue that this construction doesn't ensure browsing privacy, in the sense that the activity of computer A can still be tracked down.

For that let's consider the ISP (or a man in the middle), which intercepts the (encrpyted) communication that goes between A and V. The ISP can see that some encrypted message was sent from A to V. Then, V requested [www.google.com/private-search](http://www.google.com/private-search). Of course the actual content of the response from the web server is encrypted, but the ISP still knows which websites were visited by V. And since V is a proxy for the only user A, the ISP can deduce that all websites visited by V were actually requested by A.

**My question is:** was there a flaw in my reasoning or does this really mean, that the ISP can track down my activity (if it wants to), when I use my own VPN?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, but in short, your reasoning makes sense, however, your ISP is likely not in a position to monitor both your client PCs traffic and the traffic of your VPS (if that's from a different provider). You always design countermeasures against threats and threat actors, which are modeled in some way or another. If in your model your ISP can monitor both, then sure, this does not protect against that threat.

Comment: @GaborLengyel Thanks for the tip. I would be happy if you could refer me to a better suitable place where I can post this question.

Comment: @GaborLengyel Even with your argument in mind, I think that the ISP of the VPS (not my local ISP) can still track me down, as all of the traffic goes through it.